# C++ MPIR: Looking for example usage for mpz_sizeinbase();

Tags: c++, mpir

This is the first time I am using MPIR library.  I have to do some calculations on bigintegers. Actually those numbers can have a maximum of  2048 bits.  The first task I have to implement is to find the total number of bits in teh entered decimal value.   Thsi erquires a the use of logarithm.

In MPIR library I found that this is a simple function that gives the total number of digit in a given base, an alternative to finding logarithm which is not available in MPIR:

```
size_t mpz_sizeinbase (mpz t op, int base)
```

> Return the size of op measured in number of digits in the given base.
>   base can vary from 2
>       to 36. The sign of op is ignored, just the absolute value is used. The result will be either
>       exact or 1 too big. If base is a power of 2, the result is always exact. If op is zero the return
>       value is always 1.
>       This function can be used to determine the space required when converting op to a string. The
>       right amount of allocation is normally two more than the value returned by mpz_sizeinbase,
>       one extra for a minus sign and one for the null-terminator.
>       It will be noted that mpz_sizeinbase(op,2) can be used to locate the most significant 1 bit
>       in op, counting from 1. (Unlike the bitwise functions which start from 0, See Section

I am trying to use this function as follows in my program:

```
#include < cstdio>
#include < stdlib.h>
#include < gmpxx.h>
#include < iostream>
#include <mpirxx.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <windows.h>
void main()
{
  mpz_t opt; 
  size_t nob;
  opt=200; 
  nob= mpz_sizeinbase(opt, 10);
  cout << nob<<"\n";


}
```

The answer should be 3.

But I am getting the following error during compilation:

> Error 13  error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to
>   'mpz_t'   logicaloperations.cpp   27  1   logicaloperations
>
> Error 14  error C2664: '__gmpz_sizeinbase' : cannot convert parameter 1
>   from 'int' to
>   'mpz_srcptr'  logicaloperations.cpp   28  1   logicaloperations
>   **

This is just for testing , in my actual code I will be having values like this:

```
mpz_t opt= 111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999;
```

Can you give some pointers how to use the parameters of this function correctly?

An example would be sufficient.

Comment: Why are you posting an exact duplicate of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27599310/c-mpir-error-using-mpz-sizeinbase ??

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ trust me I am not robot:-)

Comment: Looks as we're meeting some sock puppets here.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Below is my solution. If you think it can be improved further, kindly modify  this.

Answer (score 1):

Well I was able to solve this myself. This might be required in future  by someone so I am posting it here.

```
int main()
{
 mpz_t a, b ;
 size_t nob; 
mpz_init (a); mpz_init (b);  //initialization 
mpz_set_str (b, "61754454545545454545454", 10); //large things work in strings in this world 
nob = mpz_sizeinbase(b, 2); //find how many bits are there in the binary 
cout<<nob<<"\n"; 
return 0; 

}
```

Now I got the point!

If someone can improve it further it will be of great help

Comment: Thanks; it helped me :)

Comment: wait.... if you allocate ressources, always free them ---> use mpz_init ; you have a memory leak there !